# Cakephp 3 Callback method not reached

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with the afterDelete callback method. I can't use them.

Inside one of my "Storages" plugin controllers I want to delete a record and after that I want to do some other thinks, but the callback method is not reached. I have checked this with adding a log message inside the afterDelete() callback method.

This is the controller where I removed a record:

```
namespace Storages\Controller;

class StoragecontainerBlocksController extends AppController {

   public function initialize() {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
   }

   public function ajaxDeleteBlockElement() {
       $this->autoRender = false;

       // load model
       $this->loadModel("StoragecontainerBlockElements");

       // get element id
       $elementId = $this->request->data('id');

       $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

       // delete element
       $storagecontainerBlockElement = $this->StoragecontainerBlockElements->get($elementId);
       $this->StoragecontainerBlockElements->delete($storagecontainerBlockElement);
   }
}
```

This is the (model) table where the afterDelete callback is defined:

```
  use Cake\Log\Log;
  class StoragecontainerBlockElementsTable extends Table {

   public function afterDelete(Event $event) {
       Log::debug('Got here');
   }
  }
```

**Update:**

When I debugged `Log::debug($this->StoragecontainerBlockElements);` inside the ajaxDeleteBlockElement function I got the following array inside debug.log file:

```
2017-03-31 07:03:48 Debug: Cake\ORM\Table Object
(
    [registryAlias] => StoragecontainerBlockElements
    [table] => storagecontainer_block_elements
    [alias] => StoragecontainerBlockElements
    [entityClass] => \Cake\ORM\Entity
    [associations] => Array
        (
        )

    [behaviors] => Array
        (
        )

    [defaultConnection] => default
    [connectionName] => default
```

**Update:**

```
namespace Storages\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class StoragecontainerBlockElementsTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
       parent::initialize($config);
    }

    public function afterDelete(Event $event) {
       Log::debug('Got here');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->StoragecontainerBlockElements` might not be what you think it is... debug the property to make sure it's not an auto table (an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table`).

Comment: I've updated my question with the debug results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the debugging results, `$this->StoragecontainerBlockElements` is not what you thought it is, it is a so called "auto-table" or "generic table", that is, an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of a concrete subclass thereof.

Your `StoragecontainerBlockElementsTable` class/file cannot be found/loaded for some reason, hence the fallback to `\Cake\ORM\Table`. Might be caused by

- a typo in the filename, classname, or the namespace
- or the namespace is missing completely (it's not in your question)
- or the class lives in a plugin, and you didn't used plugin notation for loading it
- or the file permissions do not allow reading file
- or the file is missing (not deployed)
- ...

See also

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > Disabling Generic Tables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#disabling-generic-tables)**

Comment: I've added my StoragecontainerBlockElementsTable class. It's a table inside a plugin with the name "Storages".

Comment: Wikked! I had to include the plugin name with the class name, separated with a dot like `$this->loadModel("Storages.StoragecontainerBlockElements");` Thanks for help. You earned my bounty!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class StoragecontainerBlockElementsTable extends Table {

    public function afterDelete($event, $entity, $options){
        Log::debug('Got here');

    }
}
```

Details [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#Cake%5CORM%5CTable::afterDelete)

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue. The message "Got here" is not in my debug.log file. Do you have some other ideas to fix my issue?

Comment: I have update code, please check the `afterDelete()` is fired or not by adding `debug()` and `die()`

Comment: When I debug the delete() function I get a "true". But how can I debug the afterDelete() when I use ajax to call the ajaxDeleteBlockElement() function? There is nothing happened when I use die() or debug() inside the afterDelete() method.