# Left Join CakePHP3

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, associations, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to do a LEFT JOIN in CakePHP3.
But all I get is a "is not associated"-Error.

I've two tables BORROWERS and IDENTITIES.
In SQL this is what I want:

```
SELECT
 identities.id
FROM
 identities
LEFT JOIN borrowers ON borrowers.id = identities.id
WHERE
 borrowers.id IS NULL;
```

I guess this is what I need:

```
$var = $identities->find()->select(['identities.id'])->leftJoinWith('Borrowers',
        function ($q) {
               return $q->where(['borrowers.id' => 'identities.id']);
        });
```

But I'm getting "Identities is not associated with Borrowers".

I also added this to my Identities Table:

```
$this->belongsTo('Borrowers', [
  'foreignKey' => 'id'
]);
```

What else do I need?
Thanx!

Comment: `$identities` is probably not what you think it is, eg it's an auto-table, that is an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of a concrete subclass thereof. Check `get_class($identities)`. **https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143901/1392379**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. It was an instance of \Cake\ORM\Table, due to my not well chosen table name (Identity/Identities). I guess it's always better not to choose those obstacles, for now I renamed it to Label/Labels.

This query now works perfectly:

```
$var = $identities 
  ->find('list')
  ->select(['labels.id'])
  ->from('labels')
  ->leftJoinWith('Borrowers')
  ->where(function ($q) {
      return $q->isNull('borrowers.id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key cannot just be 'id', that's not a correct model association.  You'd need to put a 'borrower_id' field in identities, and declare it like this in the Identities model:

```
class Identities extends AppModel {
     var $name = 'Identities';

public $belongsTo = array(
     'Borrower' => array (
          'className' =>  'Borrower',
          'foreignKey' => 'borrower_id'
           )
      );
```

Note the capitalization and singular/plural general naming conventions which your example doesn't follow in the least - ignoring those will get you some really hard to debug errors..