# CakePhP table entity incorrect

Tags: cakephp, entity

I have two tables setup as and one correctly reports the related entity where as the other reports as \Cake\ORM\Entity not App\Model\Entity\EventSubtype

I'm using TableRegistry::get on both tables and one works fine and one doesn't.  To add more confusion on another dev site both work as they should.

The code is the same as its pulled from the same repo.

["entityClass"]=> string(29) "App\Model\Entity\EventType"

["entityClass"]=> string(16) "\Cake\ORM\Entity"

The second one should be App\Model\Entity\EventSubtype

Any ideas?

Comment: Auto-tables: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097349/cakephp-3-callback-method-not-reached/43143901#43143901**

Comment: Thanks,   I used some code inside bootstrap that detects autotables.   Would updating a database on a server cause an issue like this....  One dev server they arent auto tables so want else could cause them being detected ok on one server but auto tables on another.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that the database schema has anything to do with that, but you could easily test it by rolling back the changes. I'd put my money on the issues I've mentioned in the linked answer - the first point is also affected by case sensitivity.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now but I dont understand what has changed to fix it.  As least i've learnt about auto tables now, so thank you